# String comparison: Actual newline is never recognized as "\n"

Tags: python, string, serial-port

I am trying to learn a bit of Python by writing a script to communicate with my switch over a serial connection.

```
    while char is not "\n":
        char = port.read(1)
        sys.stdout.write(char)
```

I try to compare the output and end the loop if I find a newline but it never works.

I even tried to encode some of the output to make sure that there really ARE newlines, it looks like this:

```
0000420   G   I   G   A   l   i   n   e   2   6   0   0   M       l   o
0000440   g   i   n   :      \r  \n   G   I   G   A   l   i   n   e   2
0000460   6   0   0   M       l   o   g   i   n   :      \r  \n   G   I
0000500   G   A   l   i   n   e   2   6   0   0   M       l   o   g   i
0000520   n   :      \r  \n   G   I   G   A   l   i   n   e   2   6   0 ...
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want

```
while char != "\n":
```

Using `is` in a comparison checks to see if the two objects in the comparison are the exact same object, it doesn't check to see if they just have the same value.

```
>>> char = "\n"
>>> char == "\n"
True
>>> char is "\n"
False
>>> a = char
>>> a is char
True
>>> id(a)
139751408202160
>>> id(char)
139751408202160  # char and a have the same id, thus `a == char` is True
>>> id("\n")
139751346017264  # "\n" has a different id, so `char is "\n"` is False
```

As a rule, you should only use the `is` comparison in Python when you're dealing with singleton objects, like `None`, `True`, and `False`. For strings, ints, etc. you should use `==` and `!=`.

Answer (score 0):

!= and not is not the same thing in python.

like == and is are different.

```
a = 'a'
# char is not equals a
char != 'a'
# char is not a
char is not a

# char is equals a
char == a
# char is a
char is a
```